# Plurals bug in answer-question tooltip of tags page of user profile

Tags: bug, profile-page, tooltips, plurals

The tooltip showing the score in the tags page of the user profile has the following two sentences in plural even if you've only made 1 post

> 1 non-wiki answers

> 1 non-wiki questions

See the screenshot:

[image: screenshot of tags tab in user profile]